# Amcharts multiple tooltips (ballon) on one chart in compare mode

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I have 4 stock graphs that I want to compare. When I tried to set a `ballon` properties for them I always get some redundant one.

My first idea was to specify only one `StockGraph` But I get one extra object.

```
 let chart = window.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
          "path": AmCharts_path,
          "type": "stock",
          "theme": "light",

          "dataSets": portfolioData.map(function (port) {
            return {
              "title": port.name,
              "fieldMappings": [{
                "fromField": "value",
                "toField": "value"
              }],
              "dataProvider": port.data,
              "compared": true,
              "categoryField": "date"
            }
          }),

          "panels": [{
            "showCategoryAxis": false,
            "title": "Value",
            "percentHeight": 70,
            "stockGraphs": [
              {
                "id": "g1",
                "valueField": "value",
                "comparable": true,
                "compareField": "value",
                "balloonText": "Smart Gloabal A-[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
              }
             ]
          }],

          "chartScrollbarSettings": {
            "graph": "g1"
          },

          "chartCursorSettings": {
            "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
            "fullWidth": true,
            "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
            "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
            "valueLineEnabled": true,
            "valueLineAlpha": 0.5
          },

          "listeners": [{
            "event": "zoomed",
            "method": this.calulateMetrics
          }],
```

Then I decided to remove `ballonText` property. But still this extra object exist.

```
        "stockGraphs": [
          {
            "id": "g1",
            "valueField": "value",
            "comparable": true,
            "compareField": "value",
            //"balloonText": "A-[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
            "compareGraphBalloonText": "B [[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>"
          }
         ]
```

Then I decided to describe logic for every graph, but this only increased number of my of my objects.

```
        "stockGraphs": portfolioData.map(function (port, idx) {
          return {
           "id": "g"+(idx+1),
            "valueField": "value",
            "comparable": true,
            "compareField": "value",
            "balloonText": "A-[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
            "compareGraphBalloonText": "B [[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>"
          }
        }),
```

I tried to follow examples fros the official website but didn't find relevant one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra balloon in your first screenshot comes from your first `dataSet` object. The first `dataSet` is visible by default so it does not need `compared` set to true; setting it to true will duplicate the balloon from the first `dataSet` (you can see the first `dataSet` repeat itself in the legend if it is enabled). You can fix this by tweaking your `map` call slightly:

```
      "dataSets": portfolioData.map(function (port, idx) {
        return {
          "title": port.name,
          "fieldMappings": [{
            "fromField": "value",
            "toField": "value"
          }],
          "dataProvider": port.data,
          "compared": (idx === 0 ? false : true), //don't compare the first dataSet
          "categoryField": "date"
        }
      }),
```